# Error al impirmir el contenido en un formulario php

Tags: php, html

Estoy empezando en php y tengo que hacer un formulario y que cuando se complete imprima por pantalla el contenido. El problema es que no me imprime los valores que he insertado en el formulario.

El código del formulario es el siguiente:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <form action="respuesta.php"  method="post" > 
        <br>

        <label for="nombre"> Nombre y apellidos:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" size="30" maxlength="30"  pattern= "[A-Za-z- ]+" required /> <br>
        <br><br>
        <label for="email"> Email:</label><br>
        <input type="email" id="email" size="100" maxlength="100" required /> <br>
        <br><br>
        <label for="web"> Website:</label><br>
        <input type="URL" id="web" size="100"maxlength="120"/> <br>
        <br><br>
        <label for="coment"> Comentarios: </label><br>
                <textarea name="coment" rows="10" cols="30">
                </textarea> <br>
        <br><br>
        <label for="gen"> Género:</label><br>
        <select id="gen" name="Género"> 
                    <option value="hombre">Hombre</option>
                    <option value="mujer">Mujer</option>
                    <option value="otros">Otros</option> 
                </select> <br>
        <label for="espe"> Especificar otros:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="espe" /> <br>
        <br><br>
    
             <input type="submit">
             <input type="reset">
        </form> 

        

    </body>
</html>
```

Y el del archivo php para enseñar el contenido es este:

```
 <html>

<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Pagina de confirmción </h1>
<p>Nombre: <?php echo $_POST['nombre"]; ?></p>




</body>
```

Muchas grcias.

Comment: Tus campos solo tienen ID, pero no nombre (_name_) que es lo que usa el navegador para enviarlos.

Comment: He cambiado el imput del nombre por   <input  name="nombre" type="text" id="nombre" size="30" maxlength="30"  pattern= "[A-Za-z- ]+" required /> <br> y sigue sin imprimir nada.

Comment: Solo por no dejar lugar a dudas, ¿estás usando algún servidor o abriendo directamente el HTML? Si en la barra de dirección aparece algo como `file:///ruta/archivo.html` no va a funcionar porque no hay un intérprete activo para PHP.

Comment: Estoy abriendo directamente html en firefox. ¿entonces no es posible?

Comment: Necesitas ejecutar el script en un servidor y puedes instalar fácilmente uno en tu computadora, busca en google _XAMPP_ o _Wampserver_ y elige el que se adapte a tus necesidades y sistema operativo.

Answer (score 0):

para mostrar por pantalla contenido enviado con el metodo **POST** a través de un formulario deberias manejar sesiones y utilizar `$_SESSION` para mostrar los valores por pantalla, por ejemplo: `<?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?>` imprimiría el nombre de usuario.

Para guardar estos valores manejando sesiones deberias poner session_start al principio del código y luego de registrar los valores en la base de datos con `$_SESSION` mostrarlos por pantalla con `echo` por ejemplo ten en cuenta este código:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpassword", "database");
    $usuario = "";
    $email = "";
    $password = "";
    $errors = array();
    if(isset($_POST['registrar_usuario'])) {
     $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['usuario']);
     $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
     $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
     
     if(empty($usuario)) {
      array_push($errors, "No has ingresado un nombre de usuario");
     }
     if(empty($email)) {
      array_push($errors, "No has ingresado un correo electrónico");
     }
     if(empty($password)) {
      array_push($errors, "No has ingresado una contraseña");
     }
     $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $user_check_query);
     $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  
     if ($user) { 
      if ($user['username'] === $username) {
       array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }

     if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "email already exists");
    }
  }
     if (count($errors) == 0) {
     $password = md5($password_1);
     $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) 
              VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "Ahora estás logueado!";
    header('location: index.php');
  }
}
    }
?>
```

Aquí lo que hacemos es insertar los datos registrados en el formulario en la base de datos, luego de sanitizar el formulario, validarlo y guardar los datos (si no hay errores en el proceso de registro) guardamos el nombre de usuario y el mensaje success con `$_SESSION` y esto lo podemos mostrar por pantalla en otro archivo PHP de la siguiente manera: `<?php echo $_SESSION[username]; ?>` y `<?php echo $_SESSION['success']; ?>`

Espero haberte sido de ayuda, saludos!